# iOS App Promotion Code expiration conditions

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, promotion-code

As I understand, promo-codes expire 4 weeks after generated. You are also given 50 codes per version uploaded.

But, **what would happen if you generate a promo-code, e.g. for app version 1.0, then upload a new binary/version, e.g. app version 1.1, to iTunesConnect and give out more promo-codes?**

Would the other promocodes expire immediately when the new version is ready or would they still be active until their 4-weeks are past? Also, would they then be able to download version 1.1 instead of 1.0 (on which they were generated) ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You would get 50 new promo codes for your new version.
All promo code are valid for 4 weeks, regardless of version.

Comment: This is not a complete answer to the question.

Answer (score 3):

After my app crashing mysteriously on the release side, I've been testing my own promo code on a spare iPhone.

It seems that **promo codes gives a download of the version the promo code was based on**. My app was crashing on its version 2.0, and promo codes of version 2.0 will crash. However, when I erased the app and used a promo code generated from version 2.1, it ran just fine.

edit: confirmed again with yet another two codes. They really do download the version they're generated from.

Comment: Can I just confirm that you were able to download version 2.0 (via a promo code) even after you had generated 2.1 promo codes? - thanks

Comment: I think that was the case, but it's been a while and I have no old promo codes to test it on, sorry