# Apple promo codes "become invalid if a new version of the app becomes available"?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ProvidingPromoCodes.html) says promo codes "become invalid if a new version of the app becomes available"

I just want to check the definition of "becomes available".

Do they mean the promo codes become invalid when a new version is actually available in the App Store?

I hope they don't mean they become invalid when a new build has been approved for release? As this would mean that the app is "available" to give promo codes out for.

The reason I ask is: My app is yet to be released. I want to submit a new build that has a minor bug fix, but I don't want promo codes that I have already given out to stop working if this build is accepted.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming.

Comment: from stack overflow help files: "if your question generally covers… ...software tools commonly used by programmers; and is a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development … then you’re in the right place to ask your question!"

Comment: It seems this is tied directly to your build # (eg. if you increment the build it becomes a "new" version).  See here for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8106166/ios-app-promotion-code-expiration-conditions

Comment: @AndrewLombard Great, I had googled, but didn't see that one. The answer from kamziro there seems to cover what I was asking. Thanks.